# Matlab QT libraries prevent programs from running

Tags: libraries, qt, matlab

I have `matlab` on my machine with `Compiler` toolbox. In order for compiler code to work, it needs access to libraries. They are supposed to be saved in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

So I adjusted my `.bashrc` to include:

```
MATLAB_LIB="/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/extern/bin/glnxa64"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MATLAB_LIB
```

but now i cannot run many programs from the command line, e.g.:

```
~$ gnuplot
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Network.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by gnuplot)
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.3)
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0)
gnuplot: relocation error: gnuplot: symbol qt_version_tag version Qt_5.11 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference
```

or

```
~$ vim
vim: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

or

```
~$ kate
kate: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Xml.so.5: no version information available (required by kate)
kate: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by kate)
kate: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by kate)
kate: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v95/bin/glnxa64/libQt5Widgets.so.5: no version information available (required by kate...
```

If i remove the definition of the libraries from the `.bashrc` file, all works well. Is there something that i can do to avoid these problems other than remove the path to the libraries in the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Was the Compiler Toolbox installed after you installed Matlab?

Comment: @CinaedSimson Yes.

Comment: You should type "ver" then save the file. And then reinstall Compiler Toolbox. I doubt if you should have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH at all - if it worked before you installed the Compiler Toolbox without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then everything should work after you install the Compiler Toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, at least not in your .bashrc so that it applies all the time.

Setting it when running a specific program, or to test with new/different libs is OK, e.g.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MATLAB_LIB" /path/to/matlab

This sets it just for that invocation of the program.  If you need to do this every time you run `matlab`, use a function or alias or a shell script wrapper.  e.g.:

```
alias matlab='LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MATLAB_LIB" matlab'
```

The problem is that the linux runtime dynamic linker, `ld.so`, searches LD_LIBRARY_PATH for libs **before** the default directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (& `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`), which means that libs in LD_LIBRARY_PATH override the standard system libraries.

This is useful sometimes, e.g. when testing development versions of libs, but tends to screw up your system otherwise.

In your case, matlab is probably linked against an older (or just different) version of the Qt libraries (and libpython too, by the look of it) and needs those specific versions.   Every other program installed on your system was compiled against the system lib versions and will break when you tell `ld.so` to use matlab's versions.  So, don't do that.

A quick google search came up with the following pages which explain the issue in more detail:

- [When should I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html)
- [LD_LIBRARY_PATH – or: How to get yourself into trouble!](https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180)
- [Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad](https://web.archive.org/web/20060719201954/http://www.visi.com/%7Ebarr/ldpath.html)

BTW, if you're compiling stuff, use `-L` options with your linker, and/or set `LDFLAGS`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.